# Is it possible to block/stop a duplicate stylesheet?

Tags: css

Lets say that I have a site that loads this stylesheet:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/coolstyling.css">`

Then lets say I have a widget that loads that same stylesheet. Assuming that there is no way to delete the stylesheet before uploading the site to the server, is it possible to block/stop the duplicate stylesheet from loading if it already exists?

Comment: No, but with proper caching (an `expires` header, `cache-control` instructions, etc.) on the CSS file it'll use the cached version the second time.

Comment: you could possibly give your link an id, then use a script to test if such an id already exists, but this really would be very inefficient. I would say a good cache could be a better option...